# Rails Simple Form - Control the Display of an Array Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I can't seem to figure this one out, thought I might find some direction here.

So in my current project, I'm using gems simple_form and act_as_taggable_on. The product model has `act_as_taggable_on :manufacturer_tags`. So naturally I would have a simple_form looking like this:
        <%= f.input :manufacturer_tag_list, label: "custom label", hint: "cutsom hints" %>

The manufacturer_tag_list containing an array of tags in strings,I expected the input to display:
        nissan, honda, bmw
but instead, I got:
        nissan honda bmw

How do I manipulate simple_form, so it would separate by ", " instead of space?

Thank you for your time!!

Comment: Try adding a value attribute to it. value: @product.manufacturer_tag_list.to_s

Comment: @RailsGuy Ahh~ so simple!! I really should do more RTFM....
Do you mind putting this in an answer? So I could mark it the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a value attribute to it. value:

`@product.manufacturer_tag_list.to_s`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should automatically add comma (,) between each tag. If not, make sure that you did not change your delimiter to a space:

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::TagList.delimiter = ','
```

If that still does not solve your issue, you can always use gsub to add the comma back in your string:

```
<%= f.input :manufacturer_tag_list.gsub(' ', ', '), as: :string, label: "custom label", hint: "cutsom hints" %>
```